# PHP PREG_SPLIT on numbers 1-100

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am working on some code to break down the full text of a test that will copied and pasted with the following format:

```
1. This is question number one.
A. Answer 1 
B. Answer 2
C. Answer 3
D. Answer 4
2. This is question number two.
3. This is another question, number three.

45. Ken has uses his money, $353. How much does he have after spending $214.
```

I am using the following preg_split:

```
$questions = preg_split("/[0-9]+\./", $_POST[test]);
```

My problem has come in with questions like #45 where there are numbers in the question itself and they are followed by a period.

I just want to match the numbers 1-100 followed by a period. Eg.

1.
2.
3.
4.
5. 
etc

Comment: So how would you distinguish between them if you used normal human words?

Comment: How can you say that number 1-100 followed by a period won't appear in the question anywhere?

Comment: What grade are these tests for?

Comment: The test question I included was just an example. I cannot post the actual test questions I'm working on because they are copyrighted material. @sln: they are for high schoolers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to use `multiline` flag with `^`:

```
$questions = preg_split('/^ *[0-9]+\. +/m', $_POST[test]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ^ to specify that it's the beginning of the line, using the `g` and `m` modifiers to specify global and multiline:

```
/^[0-9]+\.\s/m
```

Comment: The whole text is a single string

Comment: PCRE doesn't support `/g` does it?

Comment: `/g` is Javascript not PCRE

Comment: Touche - I guess it's implicit

Answer (score 0):

A number between 1 and 100, followed by a period, can be matched by

```
/\b(?:100|[1-9][0-9]?)\./
```

but if the actual rule is to match a number at the start of a line, use

```
/^\d+\./m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all()` instead:

```
preg_match_all('~(?:^|\R)[0-9]+\. \K.+~', $_POST['test'], $matches);
$questions = $matches[0];
```